# Run iOS application on iPad device

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I am new in iOS and I am running MAC OS using VMware. I have developed a simple iOS application in xcode 4.5 and it works fine in the simulator.

Can I run and test my application on iPad device ? and how ?

Answer (score 2):

You need be a part of iOS developer program and should have developer profile and certificate to install the app in a device. [Check this check list](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/checklist//) from apple. Also check this for learning about [developer programs.](https://developer.apple.com/programs/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have apple developer certificate.

For more information [Visit this](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action).